# wordpress variable if statement

Tags: wordpress, variables

I have a problem with defining a wordpress variable for a class.
This is my code: I created a custom field for posts with the anme class.
Here I'd like to retrieve the class. If the custom field is empty, the class should be set to "col1" by default

```
$masonry_col_class = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'class', true);
if (!empty($masonry_col_class)){ $masonry_col_class='col1'; };
```

And here's the output for the css:

```
<ul class="<?php echo $masonry_col_class ?>">
```

The if (!empty...) doesn't seem to work though.

I would be thankful for any help.
-n-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually written : if the variable I have just defined is NOT empty, then set it to "col1". You should do exactly the opposite : if the variable IS empty, like this :

```
$masonry_col_class = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'class', true);
if (empty($masonry_col_class)){ $masonry_col_class='col1'; };
```

(as I guess your idea is : either the class is defined in the custom field and we have it here, or else I use the generic "col1" class... is that correct?